# How to stop Stockfish analysis?

Tags: analysis, stockfish, chessbase

I am using Chessbase 13. I would like Stockfish to stop analyzing until I make it  start again. What happens now is that I make it stop, and as soon as I go on to the next move, it starts analyzing again. Mounting and unmounting the engine is slow. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, nevermind about my question, because I have just found an answer myself. Just click on stop, and then click the lock button. To start again, just click on the lock button to unlock it.

Comment: Don't worry. Self-answered questions are also OK for the community, as they may help someone else with the same issue in the future